# Change Character spacing in navigation bar title swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change character spacing in navigation bar title. I am trying to use the following code.

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "New Title")
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value:   CGFloat(1.4), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 9))



        self.navigationItem.title = attributedString
```

This is giving the following error :

Cannot assign a value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' to a value of type 'string?'

Can someone help me with this or suggest a different way to change character spacing in navigation bar title in swift?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not set attributed string directly.

You can do a trick by replacing `titleView`

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
let colour = UIColor.redColor()
let attributes: [NSString : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSKernAttributeName : 5.0]
titleLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "My String", attributes: attributes)
titleLabel.sizeToFit()
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Keep in mind that if you set the kerning, the centering of the text will be slighlty out. To fix this, the kerning attribute must be applied to (string.count - 1) so that character spacing is not added after the final character.

Answer (score 2):

## How to customize UINavigationBar Title AttributedText

**Swift 4.2 Version:**

```
    let titleLbl = UILabel()
    let titleLblColor = UIColor.blue

    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Noteworthy-Bold", size: 30)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: titleLblColor]

    titleLbl.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "My Title", attributes: attributes)
    titleLbl.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLbl
```

Will result a bellow like Navigation Bar Title:
[image]

Remember the `NSAttributedStringKey.font` attribute in within the Attributes dictionary follows following format:

```
NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "FontNameILike-FontStyleILike", size: 30)!
```

FontName can be anything you would like and available within iOS SDK (I have used Noteworthy) and the some of the standard font styles (I have used Bold) are as follows:

```
Bold, BoldItalic, CondensedBlack, CondensedBold, Italic, Light, LightItalic, Regular, Thin, ThinItalic, UltraLight, UltraLightItalic
```

And I hope following blog post will also be helpful (as of 19th Sep. 2018 it's still working) https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-using-attributed-string-in-navigation-bar-title-39f08f5cdb81

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ashish Kakkad have a light failure for Swift 2. 
There is an error of conversion with NSString.

So the correct code is :

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
let colour = UIColor.redColor()
let attributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSKernAttributeName : 5.0]
titleLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "My String", attributes: attributes)
titleLabel.sizeToFit()
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```